# Elegant way to extract information in Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

My question is simple, here is the line:

```
   <title><* page.title *></title>
```

i want to get the "page.title" part. I can do that by using these:

```
replacement = line.match(/\<\* .* \*\>/)  
replacement_contain = replacement.to_s.match(/ .* /).to_s.strip
```

is there any shortcut or better way to do this ?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with `nokogiri`, you should take the time to learn it. It's pretty straightforward, I am told.

Comment: @Cary, thanks for remainding me of nokogiri, have no idea why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

html = Nokogiri.HTML open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879967/elegant-way-to-extarct-information-ruby-regex')

puts html.css('title').text
# => "Elegant way to extarct information ruby regex - Stack Overflow"
```

The answer to "how do I parse HTML with regex" is ["**don't**, unless you know it will conform to strict XML rules."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693)

For example, @sawa's and @Cary's solutions, while okay if you know what content your HTML will contain, fail if you have `*>` anywhere else in your page, which is perfectly valid HTML. Use an HTML parser like Nokogiri instead (demonstrated above).

Answer (score 1):

```
"   <title><* page.title *></title>  "[/(?<=\*).*(?=\*)/].strip #=> "page.title"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is use a capture group:

```
str = "<title><* page.title *></title>"

str[/\*\s+(.*)\s+\*/,1]
  #=> "page.title"
```

The regular expression says to match on:

```
\*   : one asterisk, followed by
\s+  : one or more spaces, followed by capture group #1
(.*) : which matches all characters until it reaches the last
\s+  : string of one or more spaces in the line that is followed by
\*   : an asterisk
```

`\1` is the content of capture group #1, which is extracted and returned by [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).